# Boto S3 URL Generation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

When I use the method `generate_presigned_url` -- the resulting url contains my bucket name and path to the object and I am quite paranoid of exposing them!

Is there a way to generate a temp url that will not have the path and bucket name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to my question is No!

Discussion with boto: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1591

Apparently the work around I followed is that move the images to a new randomly named folder and generate the url! After URL expiry, delete the randomly named folder. Downside -- Time in copying the images. Space is not an issue if the url expiry is in seconds.